# Switch C3750-24PS-P

Tags: cisco-router

I have installed switch C3750 and need to install OS.  There are only two files in the device, flash_init, and boot.  There is no OS and load_helper and I have tried to use Putty to install but not working.  Showing error i/o and can you please post step by step how to install?  There is not much showing on the website with old switch c3750. Appreciated with your help!